# Combining N number of weighted probabilities

Tags: probability, predictive-models, weighted-mean

I have a question that I thought was simple but I can’t seem to find an answer.

Let’s say I have N number of models that will predict a binary event and i have an accuracy assigned to each model, for example:

Model 1 is 82% accurate,
Model 2 is 60% accurate,
Model 3 is 40% accurate,
Model 4 is 20% accurate,

How would I combine them in such a way that if model 2 and 3 gave a positive outcome, but models 2 and 4 didn’t, I would get a percentage of probability of the event occurring while taking into account model 1 is the most accurate and model 4 is the least. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd want some indication of how they performed jointly; it's not like their use of the same information would result in independent estimates.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Imagine your models were themselves variables in a logistic regression. Note that the coefficients of the variables used alone (simple logistic regression models) may be entirely different from what they'd be in a *combined* model with all the variables in it. A variable with a strong positive coefficient might well end up having a very weak negative coefficient, for example; univariate coefficients are not necessarily informative of the value of a coefficient in the presence of other predictors. Similar comments apply to the collection models. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ...  If you really want a set of positive model-weights you might perhaps consider probabilistic model-selection in a Bayesian context and form a mixture-model though it's not quite doing the same thing.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: If you treat the coefficients within each model as fixed, you might even use some binomial regression model to form a combination if you don't mind the possibility of some negative coefficients; you might also regularize such a fit. It would not necessarily be logistic regression; e.g. if you want a linear combination you might use a linear probability model as long as the domain stayed within the linear part of the model.